# Add one button to the left and another to the right in action bar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-actionbar

I want to add two buttons to my action bar. One to the left side and another to the right side. My problem is that when I'm adding them, there's no space between them and they are stretched.
This is the screenshot of both buttons:[image]

And this is the button placed alone, i want both of the buttons to look like that but each at a side:
[image]

That's the xml code im using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/font_big"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the second screenshot im not using a custom layout for the action bar. I want the buttons to have the same small size like in using the default layout of the action bar.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, you are dividing your action bar layout into two equally weighted buttons which normally gives each button half of the layout size regardless the buttons size.Check this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/font_big"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft = "true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_button"
        android:layout_alignParentRight = "true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thnx worked perfectly :) I then chnged the width of height of the buttons to  the desired size.